# Azure devops pipeline task error : Measure-Command invocation fails

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

When I debug below lines of code in VS code it works fine.But, When this code executes in azure devops (release pipeline azure powerShell task), I get below task error.
**azure powerShell Taskversion** = ~ 5.*
Is this version specific?

```
(Measure-Command {
        1..200 | ForEach-Object -Parallel $testScript -ThrottleLimit 5
    }).TotalMinutes
```

**Error:**
2020-12-16T11:25:36.6181969Z + $timeTaken = (Measure-Command {
2020-12-16T11:25:36.6183027Z +               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
2020-12-16T11:25:36.6184374Z     + CategoryInfo          : MetadataError: (:) [Measure-Command], ParameterBindingException
2020-12-16T11:25:36.6185735Z     + FullyQualifiedErrorId : AmbiguousParameterSet,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MeasureCommandCommand

Comment: Looks like issue is with ForEach-Object command. Below code throws "Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters" error.

Code:
1..100 | ForEach-Object -Parallel {Write-Host "Test"} -ThrottleLimit 5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Parameter set cannot be resolved using the specified named parameters

I could reproduce this issue. The root cause of this issue is that PowerShell 7 supports the command: `ForEach-Object -Parallel`.

This issue is related with the PowerShell Version.

Here is [the doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/whats-new/what-s-new-in-powershell-70?view=powershell-7.1#:%7E:text=PowerShell%207.0%20is%20an%20open,parallelization%20with%20ForEach%2DObject%20%2DParallel) about the Powershell 7 information:

> Pipeline parallelization with ForEach-Object -Parallel

In azure devops, WindowsPowerShell 5.1 is used by default.

To solve this issue, you need to select the option: **Use PowerShell Core** in **Azure PowerShell Task -> Advanced**:

[image]

Then it will use the Powershell 7 in the agent and the command can be executed successfully.